# discord.py moving people to different voice channels

Tags: discord.py

```
channel_a = bot.get_channel(780743421442260993)

@bot.command()
async def Movee(ctx):
    i = 0
    while i < len(participant):
        if type(participant[i]) != str:
            await participant[i].move_to(channel_a)
        i += 1
```

I want to move people to another voice chat room,

but using this code, people are just disconnected from voice chat room.

I've already checked if the channel ID is correct...

If you know the solution, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're overcomplicating your code that much? You could've wrote it in two lines. There's a ton of things wrong in this code, where have you defined `participant`? Also - why are you defining the channel outside the command?

Comment: Are you sure the channel id is a voice channel id?

Comment: The whole code is too long, so I only brought some.
Also channel id does not seem to be fixed, so I also created another command that specifies the channel id, so I defined the channel id outside the command :)

Comment: channel_a = bot.get_channel(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id)
code that receives the channel ID for reference.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a `while`-loop with an incrementing integer instead of a `for` or `for-each` loop?

Comment: There's no specific reason I keep using it because I'm used to it.. Do you recommend using for more?

Answer (score 0):

```
channel = []
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel_a = bot.get_channel(780743421442260993)   
    channel.append(channel_a)
```

```
@bot.command()
async def setChA(ctx):
    channel[0] = bot.get_channel(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.id)
    await ctx.send("Done")

@bot.command()
async def Move(ctx):
    i = 0
    while i < len(participant):
        if type(participant[i]) != str:
            await participant[i].move_to(channel[0])
        i += 1
```

It work very well change as above.

I think it's caused by the way the async function works.

It will probably work well without using `list`.

I post it for someone who will have the same problem as me.

Also I always welcome anyone who knows a better way :D